# How do I remove elements from an array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am doing the configuration file using `Config::Simple`

The configuration file i.e. new.conf

```
[Dialer External]
pass=pass2
user=user2

[Dialer Onboard]
pass=pass1
user=user1

[Dialer Onboard1]
pass=pass1
user=user1

[Dialer Onboard2]
pass=pass1
user=user1
```

I am reading the configuration file and here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Config::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

$cfg = new Config::Simple(syntax => 'ini');
$cfg->read('new.conf');
$cfg = Config::Simple->import_from('new.conf', \%Config);
my @arr = ( keys %Config );
print "@arr";
```

The hash reference i.e.`%Config` i am assigning to the array `@arr`the output would be

```
Dialer Onboard1.pass 
Dialer Onboard.pass 
Dialer Onboard.user 
Dialer Onboard2.pass 
Dialer Onboard2.user 
Dialer External.user 
Dialer External.pass 
Dialer Onboard1.user
```

Till here is correct. Now i want to remove some element and assign it to new array that should be something like this

```
Dialer Onboard1
Dialer Onboard 
Dialer Onboard 
Dialer Onboard2 
Dialer Onboard2 
Dialer External 
Dialer External 
Dialer Onboard1
```

so that after the dot (`.`) i don't want any data. For this i am trying to use the `grep` function.Here is my code for that

```
@arr = grep { !/./ } @arr;
my @result;
for (@arr) {
    if (/./) {
        push @result, $_;
    } 
}
```

But this is not working for me or it may be wrong approach. I am not able to identify where i am going wrong.
And finally i want to remove the duplicate keys from that and that gives me output something like this.

```
Dialer External 
Dialer Onboard 
Dialer Onboard1 
Dialer Onboard2
```

Please somebody help me and suggest me how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` is for filtering, not for changing the data. To remove everything after a dot, use substitution:

```
s/\..*// for @arr;
```

If you want unique elements, use a hash:

```
my %uniq;
@uniq{@arr} = ();
@arr = keys %uniq;
```

Or, use `uniq` from [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{ uniq };
@arr = uniq(@arr);
```

Comment: `grep` can be used for changing data. `@arr = grep s/\..*//, @arr` would also work in this case

Comment: @mob: Modifying $_ in `grep` is possible, but not recommended.

Comment: Is there any built-in functions u have used in first option ?

Comment: @abhishek: The first part is a hash slice asignment, the second one is normal array assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fix that gives you what you want. But I'm slightly surprised that no-one noticed what you actually wanted to do.

The reason why you are getting more complicated keys (and more keys) than you wanted is because you are using a generalised config parser to read a config file in a format that the parser isn't really suited for. Config::Simple assumes a pretty flat key/value structure, whereas the INI-style config that you actually want is more naturally represented as a two-level hash.

So if you use a real INI parser (e.g. [Config::INI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI)), your life immediately gets a lot easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Config::INI::Reader;

my $cfg = Config::INI::Reader->read_file('new.conf');
my @arr = ( keys %$cfg );

say for @arr;
```

Config::INI gives you a two-level hash where the top-level keys are the names of the blocks. And that's what you are looking for. So simply calling `keys` on that hash gives you what you want.

Using the right tool often simplifies things.

Comment: what about values??what if i want to put it both in one array..so that i can access any values with the help of keys..

Comment: As I said, what you get in `$cfg` is a reference to a two-level hash (not an array, I don't think an array would really be helpful here). The values in the first level hash are hash references representing each block in the config file. So, for example, `$cfg->{'Dialer Onboard1'}{pass}` would give you "pass1".

Comment: Useless use of hash element in void context at test2.pl line 15. i am getting this error...

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. Obviously (or, at least, I thought it was obvious) you need to do something with the result of that expression - store it in a variable, print it out, something like that.

Comment: i am not getting any value...can u show me one example..so that i will understand

Comment: Add `say $cfg->{'Dialer Onboard1'}{pass};` to the end of the code in my answer. It will print "pass1" (given the INI file in your question).

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in say at test2.pl line 13. this error is encountering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83961/discussion-between-dave-cross-and-abhishek).